# Django TabularInline through relationship

Tags: python, django

Let's say I have the following models:

```
class A(models.Model):
  pass

class B(models.Model):
  a = models.ForeignKey("A")

class C(models.Model):
  b = models.ForeignKey("B")
```

I can have a TabularInline widget showing all `B`s of a particular `A` like this:

```
class AAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  inlines = [BInline]

class BInline(admin.TabularInline):
  model = B
```

How can I have a TabularInline widget showing all `C`s of a particular `A`? (all `C`s of all `B`s of a particular `A`)

I guess I'm looking for something like:

```
class AAmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  inlines = [CInline]

class CInline(admin.TabularInline):
  model = C.through.B
```

Note: I know about the existence of `django-nested-admin`. this package will show all `C`s grouped by every `B`s, which is not what I want. I want to show only `C`s, without any references to `B`s.